# How to mix view orientations on iOS?

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, screen-rotation

I'm developing a news application. The app consists of a UITabBarcontroller, each tab representing a category of news items, held in a UINavigationController.

The app only supports portrait.

Now comes the problem. Users may post comments on news items. It is much more user friendly to be able to type comments in landscape mode. I can't seem to achieve this.

How can I support landscape for views loaded from a UINavigationController nested in a UITabbarController that only supports portrait?

I'm designing my app to be iOS 5+ compatible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can show a model view controller and it can support multiple orientations.

Comment: You mean a modal view controller? That would work for me :) Do you know how to do it? I do have modal view controllers, but they just behave in the same way my tab bar and navigation controllers do.

Comment: Eheh, yeah, __modal__ not model.